# Numpy histogram no boundaries between bins

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I wonder why the bins are not showing a boundary between each other. It's confusing to look at it. I attached an example below:

[image: Example histogram]

```
for key,value in dict.items():
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist( value, bins='auto') 
    plt.title("Histogram for THR")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: That looks correct, perhaps you are thinking of a bar graph.  In a histogram the x-axis represents a continuous variable, albeit grouped,  and the y-axis, the  count.  In a bar graph, the x-axis are for nominal data and the spacing between the bars is to show that the groupings are not connected logically.

Comment: No I don't mean a bar graph. Check out the example here :https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html. I upgraded matplotlib and Numpy recently. I know it is the correct histograms, but I want the boundaries between the bins. I don't want them all looking like a big sold fused shape.

Comment: you had better edit your post and include you frequency and key values, since the help topic example works fine for me in your link, using numpy 1.11 and matplotlib 1.5.x.  Are you using matplotlib 2.0 perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

That's the new default style for matplotlib 2.0 (for example, see the plots from the [documentation for `plt.hist` in v2.0](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/hist.html#generate-data-and-plot-a-simple-histogram)).

To force the edges of the bins to be displayed you can pass the `edgecolor=` (or `ec=`) argument to `plt.hist`, e.g. `plt.hist(values, bins='auto', ec='k')` for black bin edges.